# With two comment boxes, how to suppress comments in one of them in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog with a second textarea added as a additional field.  Both comment boxes are generating comments in the post.  The additional textarea comment box is populating the wp_metacomment database table and the main default message box is populating the wp_comments database table by default.  I want to turn off the comments coming from the main default Wordpress comments field and keep them from displaying in the page, but keep the data going into the wp_comments table.  I was thinking I could delete the main comments box and create another meta-field comments textarea box, but I was thinking there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the default comment box by adding "display:none" to the default comment box's attributes in style.css and creating a second comment box.  All of the key/value pairs are now going to the wp_commentmeta table.